# How to avoid space(s) while inserting data in a table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I want to avoid leading and trailing spaces in a column of a table. I tried using below check constraints but showing error - **"invalid relational operator"**.

```
alter table employee add (CONSTRAINT trm_name check(trim(name)));
alter table employee add (CONSTRAINT trm_name check(trim(dept)));
```

Suppose, I have a table employee, and want no leading and trailing spaces on both columns(name and dept). Could anyone please help me.

Regards,
Tarak

Comment: If `name` is a string, then `trim(name)` is also a string. A constraint should be a **condition**, not a string. This doesn't tell you how to solve your problem, but it does tell you why you are getting that error - and why you were going the wrong way about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER EMPLOYEE_BIU
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON EMPLOYEE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :NEW.DEPT := TRIM(:NEW.DEPT);
END EMPLOYEE_BIU;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Bob Jarvis ! Actually I want to use check constraint on both the columns. Is it possible to that using check constraint, please help

Comment: Bad practice - using triggers to do the job of constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, in particular, you don't want to allow non-empty strings made up **entirely** of spaces in those columns.

If so, I would write the constraints with `decode`, which handles `NULL` the way needed for constraints (in which an equality like `NULL=something` is treated the same as `TRUE` - unlike the same equality in `WHERE` clauses or join conditions, where it is treated the same as `FALSE`).

For example:

```
alter table employee 
  add (CONSTRAINT trm_name check(decode(name, trim(name), 1, 0) = 1));
```

`decode` returns `1` if and only if name is `NULL` **or** name is non-`NULL` and it has no leading or trailing spaces. It returns `0` in all other cases - if `name` is all spaces, then `trim(name)` is `NULL`, `name` is not `NULL`, so `decode` returns `0` and the constraint is `FALSE`.

Note that often we write conditions in the form `decode(a, b, 1) = 1` (the default return value of `decode` is `NULL`, so this suffices **in `WHERE` clauses and in join conditions**). In constraints, `NULL = 1` is handled the same as `TRUE`, so this shorthand will not work; we must give a non-`NULL` value in `decode` when `a` and `b` are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CHECK` constraint as follows:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE ABC (
  2  NAME   VARCHAR2(100) CHECK ( NAME = TRIM(NAME) ), -- use CHECK constraint
  3  DEPT   VARCHAR2(100) CHECK ( DEPT = TRIM(DEPT) )  -- use CHECK constraint
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> -- space in name
SQL> INSERT INTO ABC VALUES (' TEJASH ','SO');
INSERT INTO ABC VALUES (' TEJASH ','SO')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (TEJASH.SYS_C0014819) violated


SQL> -- space in department
SQL> INSERT INTO ABC VALUES ('TEJASH1',' SO');
INSERT INTO ABC VALUES ('TEJASH1',' SO')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (TEJASH.SYS_C0014820) violated


SQL> -- valid record
SQL> INSERT INTO ABC VALUES ('TEJASH1','SO');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Alas, these constraints will still allow the insertion of strings consisting entirely of spaces. In particular, the string consisting of one space (which is often used as a placeholder for NULL). This is because NULL = string has the truth value of UNKNOWN, and in constraints UNKNOWN is treated the same as TRUE.

Comment: Yes @mathguy, you are correct. But I didnt know if this is requirement of the OP or not. Thanks for your comment!!